# Are are View class subs clickable?

Tags: android, view, widget

I have a few questions than I am still unable to find an answer for:

1- The Android class documentation describes the `View` class as the **base building block for all UI components**, but at the same time describes it as **the base class for widgets** (which are used to create interactive UI components. i.e: `TextView`s, `Button`s..). Is this redundant or is it referred to something more general (basic building block for UI components)?

2 - The `View` class itself defines methods like: `setClickable`, `setEnabled`, and `isClickable`. It also has a nested class `View.OnClickListener`. It has multiple sub-classes. Some of them are clickable, and some are not. Some implement `View.OnClickListener`, and some not.

I checked the source code for its subclass `Button`, which is also a subclass of `TextView`. In the `Button` source code it does not override any method of any of its superclasses. Then where do all these differences in functionality and appearance come from? I am trying to connect things and to understand where the distinction comes from. Can anyone help?